# Black algae all over tank after 6 months

Tags: aquarium, aquatic-plants, algae

I started a planted tank with Monte Carlo. Everything was fine till first 4 months and the carpet was also coming up well.
**But after that black algae started to come all over the substrate and leaves.**

I tested my tank for **phosphates** and its zero. Still used sechem Phosguard as it removes **silicates** as well.

Not sure about **nitrates** but I do a 60% water change every week.

I also use pressurized CO2.

Also, I have 2 small tetra , 2 siamese algae eaters and 4 Amano Shrimps.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks.